# Spring security creation of new session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I'm using spring security.
I have this scenario:

1. create 2 users
2. login with the first and login again with the second before the session of user 1 expires

The correct behavior is that the first session is set expired and anew session is created.

Which spring security part is in charge of doing the expiration and creation of new session? the success handler/ authentication provider?

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is what you are looking for, if not, please let me know, I will delete my answer. You need something for session management. I have the XML code this way.

```
  <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
         <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
     </security:session-management>
```

Also the class below for sessionRegistry :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

}
```

Instead of migrateSession, you can use newSession, that way, old session will be automatically expired and a fresh one will be created.